# Using Variable inside jsx loop

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have loop like this inside jsx render

```
return(
<View>
   {[...Array(10)].map((x, i) => (
          <Input
            placeholder="Category {i}"
          />
        ))}
</View>
)
```

I am trying to create 10 inputs dynamically using above code , here I want to use the variable I inside place holder so I get the inputs with placeholder Category 1 , Category 2 etc., but my app is crashing without any error , what is the proper way to use variable inside the map of jsx.

Comment: What is Array(10)? Is this dummy to mean an array that has 10 items?

Comment: yea creating 10 items

Comment: Loop is working fine , i just want to get the count inside placeholder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this

```
return (
  <View>
    {new Array(10).map((x, i) => (
      <Input placeholder={`Category ${i + 1}`} />
    ))}
  </View>
);
```

Refer to this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 3):

You can use a javascript variable in a string wrapped by template char: "'".

And you need to set `key` in children.

```
return(
<View>
   {new Array(10).map((x, i) => (
          <Input
            key={i}
            placeholder={`Category ${i}`}
          />
        ))}
</View>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For any one wondering , I solved it by writing code like below.

```
  {[...Array(10)].map((x, i) => {
          return (
            <Input        
              placeholder={"Category " + (i + 1)}
            />
          );
        })}
```

Comment: True, that may work, but it could be cleaner, refer to my answer above.